# Delete a document from CosmosDB collection with no partition key using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Here is the code I use to delete a document:

```
const CosmosDbClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient
let client = new CosmosDbClient(URL, {
    masterKey: KEY
  })
client.deleteDocument(docUrl, {
    partitionKey: partitionKeys
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } else {
      console.log('DELETED document ' + docUrl)
    }
  })
```

It works for a collection with partition key. For such a case I pass `['myPartitionKey']` for `partitionKeys` variable. But I am lost for collection that does not use partitioning.

A number of issues and PRs in azure-documentdb-node and vscode-cosmosdb cross reference each other.

What I also did not understand is why instead of fixing documentdb npm package repository the fixes are made in vscode-cosmosdb.

[This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/issues/195) issue mentions the problem and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/issues/222) possible solution is shared.

Although I tried passing `null, undefined and {}`, nothing worked. I am getting:

`Partition key provided either doesn't correspond to definition in the collection or doesn't match partition key field values specified in the document.`

Comment: Is your collection a partitioned collection and you simply did not provide the partition key value for the document you're trying to delete or the collection is not a partitioned collection? Which one is the case?

Comment: @GauravMantri my collection is a small one. I do not use a partitioning for it.

Comment: Then I think passing `{}` as second parameter should work. This is how we're using in our code. `client.deleteDocument(docUrl, {}, (err) => {})`.

Comment: I tried it once again now, after your comment. It returns the error with the message mentioned in the question above. My documentdb npm package version is `1.14.5`.

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov Hi,any updates now?

Comment: @JayGong let me try it with your package version 1.14.2. I will write back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did two tests for you. My documentdb npm package version is `1.14.2`

***First situation:*** Want to delete document which is not defined partition key in partitioning collection.

***sample documents:***

[image]

***delete code：***

```
var config = require("./config");

var docUrl= "dbs/db/colls/coll/docs/3"

const CosmosDbClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient
let client = new CosmosDbClient(config.endpoint, {
    masterKey: config.primaryKey
  })
client.deleteDocument(docUrl, {
    partitionKey: {}
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw err
    } else {
      console.log('DELETED document ' + docUrl)
    }
  })
```

[image]

***Second situation:*** Want to delete document which is not defined partition key in non-partitioning collection.

***sample documents:***

[image]

***delete code：***

```
var config = require("./config");

var docUrl= "dbs/db/colls/import/docs/3"

const CosmosDbClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient
let client = new CosmosDbClient(config.endpoint, {
    masterKey: config.primaryKey
  })
client.deleteDocument(docUrl, {
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw err
    } else {
      console.log('DELETED document ' + docUrl)
    }
  })
```

[image]

Hope it helps you.